# add_action located in a class method in plugins do not work when called outside the plugin file

Tags: php, wordpress, class, plugins, themes

I have a simple and single class located in a file in its own directory in plugins.

The class has just one purpose, and that is to remove some unwanted wordpress actions using `remove_action`, it works just as a simple wrapper for a number of `remove_action()` function calls.

Now, the problem is, when trying to instantiate the class outside its own file. Then all the `remove_action()` function calls does not do its job, but still returning `TRUE` as in, success. This was discovered while trying to debug the simple class.

If I instantiate the class and call its only function within the same file where class is, everything works like a charm. Weird? Could be only me, but I really want to call the plugin class methods outside its own file, like in theme files.

Did anyone had this problem while developing plugins?

```
<?php
// removed the plugin stuff...

class WPStylesheetLoader
{
    public $styles = array();

    public function add($identifier, $url)
    {
        $this->styles[] = array('identifier' => $identifier, 'url' => $url);
    }

    public function enqueueAll()
    {
        foreach($this->styles as $style)
        {
            wp_enqueue_style($style['identifier'], $style['url']);
        }
    }

    public function activate() {
        echo add_action('get_header', array(&$this, 'enqueueAll'));
    }
}

$stylesheet = new WPStylesheetLoader;
$stylesheet->add('normalize', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/css/normalize.css');
$stylesheet->add('style', get_bloginfo('stylesheet_url'));
$stylesheet->add('media-queries', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/css/media-queries.css');
$stylesheet->activate();
```

Answer (score 1):

Some errors and strange things:

- `echo add_action()` **does not** exist. It's simply `add_action()`.
- The correct hook to print the enqueued styles **and** scripts is `wp_enqueue_scripts`.
- You're doing a *plugin* but loading styles from a *theme*?
- The theme `style.css` is always loaded, why are you enqueuing `get_bloginfo('stylesheet_url')`?
- `&$this` is PHP 4 code, drop the `&`.

The following works, I've added a `__construct` so as to register the plugin's URL:

```
class WPStylesheetLoader
{
    public $styles = array();
    public $plugin_url;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->plugin_url = plugins_url( '/', __FILE__ );
    }

    public function add( $identifier, $url )
    {
        $this->styles[] = array(
            'identifier' => $identifier, 
            'url'        => $this->plugin_url . $url 
        );
    }

    public function enqueueAll()
    {
        foreach( $this->styles as $style )
            wp_enqueue_style( $style['identifier'], $style['url'] );
    }

    public function activate() 
    {
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'enqueueAll' ) );
    }
}

$stylesheet = new WPStylesheetLoader;
$stylesheet->add( 'normalize', 'css/normalize.css' );
$stylesheet->add( 'media-queries', 'css/media-queries.css' );
$stylesheet->activate();
```